# ошибка python: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory при запуске докера

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Есть проект Джанго, который я пытаюсь запустить в докер.
Файл requirements.txt находится в "C:\Users\Alex Konkin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\myrepo\freeipa-password-reset_test".

Файл Dockerfile находится в "C:\Users\Alex Konkin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\myrepo\freeipa-password-reset_test".

Файл manage.py находится в "C:\Users\Alex Konkin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\myrepo\freeipa-password-reset_test\PasswordReset".

Контейнер создал так: "PS C:\Users\Alex Konkin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\myrepo\freeipa-password-reset_test> docker build -t ipa_container_test ."

Запуск контейнера: "PS C:\Users\Alex Konkin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\myrepo\freeipa-password-reset_test> docker run ipa_container_test".

Ошибка: "python: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Файл Dockerfile содержит следующий код:

```py
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN apt update
RUN apt install gcc -y

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV ENV_FILE .env

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Я новичок в джанго, а тем более в докер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.